# How to change two character strings of dates to matching formats in R

Tags: r, lubridate

So I have two character vectors.

```
"6/17/2019"
"6/27/2019"
"6/5/2019"
"12/27/2019"
```

And

```
"13-Jul-18"
"6-Nov-19"
"2-Feb-18"
```

I would like the format of all my dates to be like the first set. I tried using `strptime` to achieve this, but with no luck. I am thinking `lubridate` might be a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert to date first :

```
x <- c("13-Jul-18", "6-Nov-19", "2-Feb-18")
x1 <- as.Date(x, '%d-%b-%y')
```

Or using `lubridate`

```
x1 <- lubridate::dmy(x)
x1
#[1] "2018-07-13" "2019-11-06" "2018-02-02"
```

then you can use `format` to get data in desired format

```
format(x1, '%m/%d/%Y')
#[1] "07/13/2018" "11/06/2019" "02/02/2018"
```